# Steht der Name »Kevin« für etwas Besonderes? (z.B. in »Sei kein Kevin«)

Tags: single-word-request, slang, sociolinguistics

Ich verstehe nicht, was an dem Satz *Sei kein Kevin!* lustig sein soll. Das erste Mal, das ich den hörte, schien er mir ein Insiderwitz zu sein. Neulich sah ich aber den Ausdruck auf einem Zettel und daher vermute, dass der von jedem zu verstehen sein könnte. Nachdem ich nochmals fragte, meinten meine Bekannten, dass der Name einen Jungen mit niedrigem Bildungsniveau darstellt. Falls das stimmt, warum ausgerechnet *Kevin*?

Comment: Such mal nach Kevinismus. Du findest u.a. https://www.welt.de/politik/article1727650/Wie-Namen-die-Zukunft-von-Kindern-beeinflussen.html

Comment: Close-vote zurückgezogen ^^

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Im Jahr 1990 kam der Film [Kevin – Allein zu Haus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_%E2%80%93_Allein_zu_Haus) in die Kinos, und tausende werdende Eltern fanden die Hauptfigur so süß, dass sie die eigenen Kinder danach benannten. Damit stieg der Anteil der Kevins in der Bevölkerung ab den 1990er-Jahren sprunghaft an. Auch die Beliebtheit des Schauspielers Kevin Kostner hat sehr zu diesem Trend beigetragen.

Allerdings war dieser Effekt nicht in allen Bevölkerungsgruppen gleichermaßen ausgeprägt. In gesellschaftlichen Schichten, die eher auf die Bewahrung traditioneller Werte bedacht sind, wurde Neugeborene kaum der name Kevin gegeben. Dort war und ist es üblich, Kinder nach nahen Verwandten zu benennen, oder Vornamen zu verwenden, die sonst in diesen Kreisen verbreitet sind (z.B. Alexander, Sebastian, Maximilian). Das sind aber auch genau die Schichten, in denen der Besuch einer höheren Schule und die Absolvierung einer universitären Ausbildung üblich sind (»Bildungsbürger«).

Somit tauchten die vielen jungen Kevins der 1990er-Jahre vor allem in Familien auf, in denen es nicht typisch ist, sich stark mit Bildung auseinanderzusetzen.

Das lässt folgenden Schluss zu, der zwar in der Verallgemeinerung gilt, dessen Anwendung auf Einzelpersonen aber höchst problematisch ist:

> Wenn jemand den Vornamen *Kevin* trägt, gehört er eher einer bildungsfernen Bevölkerungsgruppe an, als einer bildungsnahen.

Wie schon gesagt: Das ist nur als statistische Aussage über die Gesamtbevölkerung haltbar, aber äußerst problematisch, wenn man ohne weitere Informationen bei Einzelpersonen vom Vornamen auf den Bildungsgrad schließen würde.

Was für Kevin gilt, gilt großteils eigentlich für alle Vornamen, die aufgrund einer Modeerscheinung vergeben wurden, z.B. Justin, Chantal, Jaqueline usw.

Comment: Also, auch in Österreich wirkt der Name so. Auch das mit *Chantal* habe ich gehört...

Comment: Ich denke, *Kevin Costner* und *Kevin allein zu Haus* (beim Titel tut sich übrigens die Frage auf, ob der überhaupt richtig ist, aber das ist eine andere - richtig zitiert hast du ihn auf jeden Fall) haben mit dem Kevin aus der Frage nix zu tun, schliesslich sind das eher Idol und Held - Für den Rest allerdings +1

Comment: @c.p.: Wie kommst du auf Österreich? Ich bezog mich in meiner Antwort auf keine bestimmte geographische oder politische Region, sondern auf die deutsche Sprache. Sie ist Amtssprache in der EU, in Deutschland, Österreich, der Schweiz, in Belgien, Luxemburg und Liechtenstein und in einem Teil Italiens (Südtirol). Außerdem ist sie Nationalsprache in Namibia und anerkannte Minderheitensprache ich einem guten Dutzend weiterer Staaten.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist falsch Hubert Schölnast. Das hat nichts mit kevin allein zu haus/in new York zu tun. Kevin, Chantal, Sandy, Sindy, Jaqueline sind halt so Beispielhafte Namen von Kindern deren Eltern nicht gerade zu den hellsten Kerzen auf der Torte gehören. Es ist ein Klischee !!

Comment: @Squareoot Ich habe die These von Hubert allerdings auch schon gehört. Sogar die entsprechende Begründung: Die »niederen Bildungsschichten« haben es toll gefunden, wie Kevin zurecht kommt und sich gegen die Einbrecher zur Wehr setzt, und in ihm ein Vorbild für die eigenen Kinder gesehen, die »höheren Bildungsschichten« waren entsetzt, wie die Eltern ihren eigenen Sohn vergessen haben können, und haben nichts vorbildliches in ihm gesehen. Habe aber leider gerade keine Quelle zur Hand.

Comment: @Squareoot Was meinst du genau mit *den hellsten Kerzen auf der Torte*?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Eine Frage war eigentlich gemeint, dooferweise habe ich aber das Fragezeichen vergessen. Es hat mich einfach erstaunt, dass das ein Phänomen nicht nur in Deutschland sich ereignet. Du kommst aber aus Österreich, und ich hätte erwartet dass wenn du etwas Unterschiedliches da beowachtet hättest, so hättest du dies geschrieben. Daher meine Vermutung.

Comment: @c.p. Wer nicht die hellste Kerze auf der Torte ist, ist – etwas einfacher gesagt – nicht der Hellste, oder schlicht etwas begriffsstutzig, vielleicht dumm, usw.

Comment: @Jan Danke schön! : )